# Parse Ienumerable with XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I cannot figure out how to parse my xml that has multiple elements with the same name and write them out or assign them to a string array so i can use them in my web app. I keep getting told Ienumerable can't be converted to string. I am really trying to simply grab each item out of the XML so I can use it.

```
if (Request.QueryString["Keywords"] != null)
        {
            string keywords = Request.QueryString["Keywords"];
            string myAppID = "HIDDEN FROM STACKOVERFLOW";
            var xml = XDocument.Load("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" + myAppID + "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=" + keywords + "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10");
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";

 var titles = from item in xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "title")
                              select new
                              {
                                  title = item.Parent.Element("title").Value,
                              };
            Label1.Text = titles.ToString();
        }
```

The example XML I have is:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
<ack>Success</ack>
<version>1.12.0</version>
<timestamp>2012-06-23T19:54:46.019Z</timestamp>
<searchResult count="10">
<item>
<itemId>120933737016</itemId>
<title>
Apple MacBook Pro 13.3" Laptop - MC700LL/A (February, 2011) 8GB 320GB *GEM MINT*
</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<subtitle>
* GEM MINT, LION, 8GB RAM, ALWAYS stored in Speck Case
</subtitle>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>111422</categoryId>
<categoryName>Apple Laptops</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>
http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/1209337370164040_1.jpg
</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-13-3-Laptop-MC700LL-A-February-2011-8GB-320GB-GEM-MINT-/120933737016?pt=Apple_Laptops
</viewItemURL>
<productId type="ReferenceID">99741550</productId>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>false</autoPay>
<postalCode>98296</postalCode>
<location>Snohomish,WA,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">17.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>US</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">811.99</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">811.99</convertedCurrentPrice>
<bidCount>14</bidCount>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P0DT0H5M24S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2012-06-16T20:00:10.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2012-06-23T20:00:10.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>Auction</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>false</returnsAccepted>
<galleryPlusPictureURL>
http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/120933737016_1_0_1.jpg
</galleryPlusPictureURL>
<condition>
<conditionId>3000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>Used</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>261037967463</itemId>
<title>
2009 Apple MACBOOK 2.13GHz Core 2 Duo / 160GB HDD / 2GB RAM / 1 YEAR WARRANTY!
</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>111422</categoryId>
<categoryName>Apple Laptops</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>
http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/pict/2610379674634040_1.jpg
</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>
http://www.ebay.com/itm/2009-Apple-MACBOOK-2-13GHz-Core-2-Duo-160GB-HDD-2GB-RAM-1-YEAR-WARRANTY-/261037967463?pt=Apple_Laptops
</viewItemURL>
<productId type="ReferenceID">85150888</productId>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>true</autoPay>
<postalCode>92101</postalCode>
<location>San Diego,CA,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Free</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>US</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">498.0</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">498.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P10DT6H30M15S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2012-06-04T02:20:01.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2012-07-04T02:25:01.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
<condition>
<conditionId>2500</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>Seller refurbished</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>271003897097</itemId>
<title>
Apple MacBook Pro 15.4" Laptop (February, 2011) - Customized
</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<subtitle>Apple Care till June 2014 - Like NEW!</subtitle>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>111422</categoryId>
<categoryName>Apple Laptops</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>
http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/pict/2710038970974040_1.jpg
</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-4-Laptop-February-2011-Customized-/271003897097?pt=Apple_Laptops
</viewItemURL>
<productId type="ReferenceID">108789851</productId>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>true</autoPay>
<postalCode>94536</postalCode>
<location>Fremont,CA,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">35.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>US</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>2</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">1399.99</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">1399.99</convertedCurrentPrice>
<bidCount>0</bidCount>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P0DT0H10M50S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>true</buyItNowAvailable>
<buyItNowPrice currencyId="USD">1750.0</buyItNowPrice>
<convertedBuyItNowPrice currencyId="USD">1750.0</convertedBuyItNowPrice>
<startTime>2012-06-22T20:05:36.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2012-06-23T20:05:36.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>AuctionWithBIN</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>false</returnsAccepted>
<galleryPlusPictureURL>
http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/271003897097_1_0_1.jpg
</galleryPlusPictureURL>
<condition>
<conditionId>3000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>Used</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
</item>
<item>
<itemId>221050903140</itemId>
<title>Apple MacBook 13.3" Laptop - MB062LL/A (2006)</title>
<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
<primaryCategory>
<categoryId>111422</categoryId>
<categoryName>Apple Laptops</categoryName>
</primaryCategory>
<galleryURL>
http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/2210509031404040_1.jpg
</galleryURL>
<viewItemURL>
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-MacBook-13-3-Laptop-MB062LL-A-2006-/221050903140?pt=Apple_Laptops
</viewItemURL>
<productId type="ReferenceID">78092354</productId>
<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
<autoPay>false</autoPay>
<postalCode>80524</postalCode>
<location>Fort Collins,CO,USA</location>
<country>US</country>
<shippingInfo>
<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">20.0</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>US</shipToLocations>
<expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
<handlingTime>3</handlingTime>
</shippingInfo>
<sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">250.0</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">250.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
<bidCount>0</bidCount>
<sellingState>Active</sellingState>
<timeLeft>P0DT0H13M21S</timeLeft>
</sellingStatus>
<listingInfo>
<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
<startTime>2012-06-18T20:08:07.000Z</startTime>
<endTime>2012-06-23T20:08:07.000Z</endTime>
<listingType>Auction</listingType>
<gift>false</gift>
</listingInfo>
<returnsAccepted>false</returnsAccepted>
<condition>
<conditionId>3000</conditionId>
<conditionDisplayName>Used</conditionDisplayName>
</condition>
<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>
</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</searchResult>
<paginationOutput>
<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
<entriesPerPage>10</entriesPerPage>
<totalPages>11900</totalPages>
<totalEntries>118994</totalEntries>
</paginationOutput>
<itemSearchURL>
http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=%22macbook%22&_ddo=1&_ipg=10&_pgn=1
</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsByKeywordsResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

Return value from IEnumerable could be converted to Array (or List) by `titles.ToArray()`, after that, you could [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) strings of array, like below:

```
label1.Text = String.Join(",", titles .ToArray());
```

Also if you like to connect all of them without any delimiter simply adding them up with a simple for loop:

```
foreach(var item in titles)
{
    label1.Text += item;
}
```

<sub>PS: I think you need multiple labels not one label for all of them</sub>

Comment: neither of those worked for me. The first one gives me an error saying the call is ambigious between the properties. The second method gives me NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.